# Why does f_write cause the program to freeze on pi pico?

Tags: c, sdk, raspberry-pi-pico, fatfs

I'm making an audio recorder with a pi pico along with an SD card connected via SPI.
Core0 gets samples from the ADC and sends them to core1 which handles SD writing.
I've isolated the issue to f_write. I commented to mark the problematic section.
Note that when I comment out that section the code runs as expected otherwise it freezes. The file shows up on the SD but it is empty.

This is the section of code from core1 that is causing the issue.

START_REC, STOP_REC, and QUIT are just #define's of numbers larger than the adc range (4096<)

```
void core1_main()
{
  sleep_ms(1000); // ensures there is no conflict with core0 when working w/ LCD
  bool brk = false;
  uint buf_size = 32000;
  uint16_t data_buffer[buf_size];
  uint buf_pos = 0;
  uint bytes_read = 0;
  uint val = 0;
  
  FRESULT fr;
  FATFS fs;
  FIL fil;
  unsigned short file_num = 0;
  char filename[20];
  filename_gen(&filename[0], file_num);

  // Init sd driver
  if (!sd_init_driver())
    {
      clrLCD();
      setString("!INIT");
      posCursor(12, 1);
      brk = true;
    }

  // mount sd
  fr = f_mount(&fs, "0:", 1);
  if (fr != FR_OK)
    {
      clrLCD();
      setString("!MOUNT");
      posCursor(12, 1);
      brk = true;
    }

  // open file for writing
  fr = f_open(&fil, filename, FA_WRITE | FA_CREATE_ALWAYS);
  if (fr != FR_OK)
    {
      clrLCD();
      setString("!F OPEN");
      posCursor(12, 1);
      brk = true;
    }

  if (!brk)
    {
      setString("Ready.");
    }

  bool rec = false;
  while (!brk)
    {
      val = multicore_fifo_pop_blocking();

      switch (val)
    {
    case QUIT:
      brk = true;
      break;
    case START_REC:
      if (!rec)
        {
          rec = true;
        }
      break;
    case STOP_REC:
      if (rec)
        {
              rec = false;
        }
      break;
    default:
      if (val < 4096)
        {
          data_buffer[buf_pos] = val;
          buf_pos++;
        }
      
        if (buf_pos > buf_size - 1)
          {
            // problematic section
            fr = f_write(&fil, data_buffer, buf_size*2, &bytes_read);
            if (fr != FR_OK)
              {
                clrLCD();
                setString("!F WRITE");
                posCursor(12, 1);
                rec = false;
              }
            f_sync(&fil); // flush sync. Prevents data loss if program fails before f_close
            // end of problematic section
            buf_pos = 0;
          }
      break;
    }
      
    }
  f_close(&fil);
  // unmount drive
  f_unmount("0:");
}
```

Another thing to note is that fr seemingly returns FR_OK or crashes beforehand because the LCD does not display "!F WRITE".

Comment: Why do you call filename_gen twice?

Comment: Just noticed that. That's leftover from when I had it setup to create a new file for each recording. I copied it outside of the loop to factor out issues. While it is useless it wouldn't affect anything really.

Comment: SD card's FTL is doing some internal job and holding busy state?

Comment: What size is the stack? AFAIK it defaults to 2048 bytes, which is not enough for 64000 bytes of data_buffer.

Comment: Not sure on the stack size. I'll look into it

Comment: I tried shrinking the write buffer to 1024 and 512. Both have the same issue.

Comment: Tried a different SD card and now the LCD is displaying "!F_WRITE"

Comment: Added some code to get the exact error and got FR_DISK_ERR

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to pass in the pointer to the data buffer in f_write() and lower the buffer size to 512 or 1024.

```
void core1_main()
{
  sleep_ms(1000);
  bool brk = false;
  uint buf_size = 512;
  uint16_t data_buffer[buf_size];
  uint buf_pos = 0;
  uint bytes_read = 0;
  uint val = 0;
  
  FRESULT fr;
  FATFS fs;
  FIL fil;
  unsigned short file_num = 0;
  char filename[20];
  filename_gen(&filename[0], file_num);

  // Init sd driver
  if (!sd_init_driver())
    {
      clrLCD();
      setString("!INIT");
      posCursor(12, 1);
      brk = true;
    }

  // mount sd
  fr = f_mount(&fs, "0:", 1);
  if (fr != FR_OK)
    {
      clrLCD();
      setString("!MOUNT");
      posCursor(12, 1);
      brk = true;
    }

  // open file for writing
  //file_num++;
  //filename_gen(&filename[0], file_num);
  fr = f_open(&fil, filename, FA_WRITE | FA_CREATE_ALWAYS);
  if (fr != FR_OK)
    {
      clrLCD();
      setString("!F OPEN");
      posCursor(12, 1);
      brk = true;
    }

  if (!brk)
    {
      setString("Ready.");
    }

  bool rec = false;
  while (!brk)
    {
      val = multicore_fifo_pop_blocking();

      switch (val)
    {
    case QUIT:
      brk = true;
      break;
    case START_REC:
      if (!rec)
        {
          rec = true; // rec value is a bit redundant but will be useful later
        }
      break;
    case STOP_REC:
      if (rec)
        {
          rec = false;
        }
      break;
    default:
      if (val < 4096)
        {
          data_buffer[buf_pos] = val;
          buf_pos++;
        }
      
      if (buf_pos >= buf_size)
        {

          if (rec)
            {
              fr = f_write(&fil, &data_buffer, buf_size*2, &bytes_read);
              if (fr != FR_OK)
                {
                  getFSerr(fr);
                  rec = false;
                }
              f_sync(&fil); // flush sync. Prevents data loss if program fails before f_close
            }
              buf_pos = 0;
        }
      break;
    }
      
  }
  f_close(&fil);
  // unmount drive
  f_unmount("0:");
}
```